# Returning multiple cfquery result back to AJAX call

Tags: json, ajax, coldfusion, cfc

I'm building a webpage that upon webform submission will make an AJAX call. AJAX then calls a cfc, where there's a function that calls a SQL stored procedure passing the webform values as input arguments. Till here is fine, but I'm confused over how to return data back to the calling AJAX function - when there are multiple resultsets returned by the stored procedure.

To make it more clear, the stored procedure internally has many SELECT transactions and each of these are being captured as part of cfprocresult in the cfstoredproc. If it was only one cfprocresult, passing it back to AJAX seems straight forward, but how do I send multiple cfprocresult results back to the calling AJAX function?

Pseudo code below:

AJAX:
—————————

```
    $.ajax(

        {

            type: “post”,

            url: "Contacts.cfc",

            data: {

                method: "retrieveCustomers",

                username: this.DOMReferences.Name.val(),



                },

            dataType: "json",





            success: function( objResponse ){



                if (objResponse.SUCCESS){



// rest of AJAX to process returned data here
```

Contacts.cfc
—————————

```
<cfcomponent>
 <cffunction name="retrieveCustomers" returntype="query">

<cfstoredproc datasource="#application.dsn_spoon#" procedure="proc_getUsers_paged">
      <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#username#">
      <cfprocresult name="qResult1" resultset="1">
      <cfprocresult name="qResult2" resultset="2">
      <cfprocresult name="qResult3" resultset="3">
</cfstoredproc>


// how do i return all 3 result sets back to calling AJAX function?

 </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

NOTE: I've very little control to change the stored procedure logic. Existing webpage was using a refresh of the page itself while calling the cfstoredproc component, and not using AJAX. I'm rewriting the UI to use AJAX instead.

Thanks!

Comment: I think what you can do is create a structure and store the result sets in it. And then use SerializeJSON function to convert the structure into JSON and returns it to Ajax as response. Once u have get the Ajax response all you need to do is parse  and manipulate it further.

Comment: Also if you are directly calling your CFC function using ajax then you need to set access=remote and  set returntype=JSON

Comment: @Keshavjha - Thank you. I think I understand the approach now. Will try it out in sometime!

Comment: There are other options available depending on what you intend to do with the results.  For example, you could use ColdFusion's `<cfsavecontent>` to create an html string, return that, and use javascript's innerHtml to display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
<cfcomponent>
<cffunction name="retrieveCustomers" returntype="struct" returnformat="json" access="remote">

<cfstoredproc datasource="#application.dsn_spoon#" procedure="proc_getUsers_paged">
      <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#username#">
      <cfprocresult name="qResult1" resultset="1">
      <cfprocresult name="qResult2" resultset="2">
      <cfprocresult name="qResult3" resultset="3">
</cfstoredproc>

<cfset _results = structNew()>
<cfset _results.result1 = qResult1>
<cfset _results.result2 = qResult2>
<cfset _results.result3 = qResult3>

<cfreturn _results> 


</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

The caveat here is that you may need to massage the qResults.  Normally, I would loop through each query and build an array. But that's just personal preference.  What I typically do when returning back a query is loop over it and build a new structure.  This is because I may want to perform addition actions against each property.

```
...
<cfset _results = structNew()>
<cfset _results.result1 = arrayNew()>
<cfset _results.result2 = arrayNew()>
<cfset _results.result3 = arrayNew()>

<cfloop query="qResult1">
    <cfset _result = structNew()>
    <cfset _result.col1 = qResult1.col1>
    <cfset _result.col2 = qResult1.col2>
    <cfset _result.col3 = qResult1.col3>
    <cfset arrayAppend(_results.result1,_result)>
</cfloop>

<cfloop query="qResult2">
    <cfset _result = structNew()>
    <cfset _result.cola = qResult2.cola>
    <cfset _result.colb = qResult2.colb>
    <cfset _result.colc = qResult2.colc>
    <cfset _result.cold = qResult3.cold>
    <cfset arrayAppend(_results.result2,_result)>
</cfloop>

<cfloop query="qResult3">
....
</cfloop>

<cfreturn _results>
```

For me, this is cleaner and easier to work with.  It may require more overhead and server side processing, but it's easier to maintain.  And there is no parsing on the JS side because structure returned is in proper JSON formatting.

Comment: Thank you! Fairly new to using structures, so two follow up questions - 
a. qResult1, qResult2, ... - these can have different number of columns being returned, right? As in, qResult1 being output of table1 and qResult2 being output of table2 where table1 and table2 are totally different tables, this would not cause any problems when i make it a structure - correct?

b. could you please add more details on the "caveat" part? I didnt quite get why i would need to massage the qResults. I'm thinking of passing the data back to AJAX and then parsing it there. 

thanks again!

Comment: Think of a structure as a container for other variables.  It doesn't matter what type of variables (simple, array, query, other structure, etc) they are.  The container will accept anything.

Comment: Yes, the qResult1, qResult2... can have different columns.  Think of a structure as an object.  Structures have properties which can be a value, another structure, or an array.  By massaging, I should have added "...on the javascript side".  It's been a while since I've returned a query object directly back to javascript.  I'll amend my answer with what I typically do.

Comment: Thank you! This part of the code suited what I was looking for like magic!
<cfset _results = structNew()>
<cfset _results.result1 = qResult1>
<cfset _results.result2 = qResult2>
<cfset _results.result3 = qResult3>

<cfreturn _results>